# OAuth 2.0 and Open ID Connect: Standard way to integrate multiple Open ID Connect endpoints without dedicated links/buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, federated-identity

We are implementing OAuth to our existing multi-tenant web app.  Many of our tenants have Open ID Connect endpoints, which we need to integrate.  Most of the examples on the internet shows having a dedicated button for each OAuth/Open ID Connect provider (Google, Facebook, et.).  We definitely don't want to have a dozen buttons on our login page or even show all of the clients' names there. The solution we currently have in mind is using a federated auth server (around [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4)), which hosts a centralized login page, and taking the user there whenever login is required.  We can follow a common username format such as email ID.  When a user enters the credentials, we can read the domain name from the email ID to determine which Open ID Connect endpoint the user should be authenticated against.  Here, we have in consideration two variations of this flow:

1) Asking for the user's user name and password on the Identity Server's login page itself and relaying them to the appropriate Open ID Connect endpoint as an API call for token retrieval.  What makes us a little leery of doing this is a potential security concern from the clients for asking their external passwords on a site maintained by us (of course we are not storing it).

2) Ask for the email ID only first.  When the user completes entering it, determine the Open ID connect endpoint based on user's domain, and redirect them to the login page of the client; the user actually enters the password on client's login page. This may be a bit more involved to implement than the option 1.

So, the question here is:  Is there a standard way of how to deal with such a situation in OAuth world?

Comment: Why don't you send tenantid when user is redirected to identityserver? This enables you to identify user tenant. Then you can redirect user to tenant login page.

Comment: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html